# Accidentally Removed SD Card

Tags: sd-card

I was just experimenting with using USB sticks on Linux, as I'm fairly new but enjoy programming. I went to eject the USB drive but at the last second jerked my hand upwards. The main SD card was "ejected".

I'm not sure if rebooting is okay to do or if there are steps to take. The actual interface seems fine (X desktop & TTY shell, and nothing seems to be affected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accidentally removing the sd card, or accidentally unpowering the Pi while it is running *can* corrupt the sd card, but it doesn't always corrupt it. If you see everything as working fine, then it looks like you're one of the lucky ones. Your card should be ok. Rebooting is safe, as well as any other commands.

If you start to notice kernel panics and whatnot later, then you might want to reinstall your OS, after backing up any important files of course.

The only time an sd card gets corrupted is when you eject it or unplug the Pi while it is writing to the card, e.i. the green ACT light is on.

Answer (score 2):

The OS will do a filesystem check at boot if it has reason to believe it was not properly unmounted during shutdown before.  This will add some seconds to your boot time and should be noticeable if you have a screen attached and are using a non-graphical boot.

If after that everything seems okay, it is probably okay.  If you are paranoid you can always take it out and run `e2fsck` on the root filesystem in another computer (you cannot do it effectively with the card in the pi because that filesystem must be mounted).

Answer (score 2):

Just point out that with latest Raspbian Jessie and Raspbian Jessie Lite builds the e2fsck is run at boot up to check and fix problems.