# Accidentally removed the sd card while it was running

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card

I am doing university project on RPi, how can I boot the raspbian now? Preferable to keep the data in it as it is very important for the project. Now it has only power led switched on.

Please, help

Comment: Sounds like the file system is corrupted.  Best bet is to use a Linux machine to try to pull the important data off, then create a new bootable card from NOOBS and then load it back.  But basically, you just did the one thing never to do with any Linux-based system.  Now you know.  If nothing else, you have learned the importance of backing up your SD cards.  https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17789160-backing-up-and-restoring-your-raspberry-pis-sd-card  Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Be sure to look at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: Is the [Green LED blinking in a specific pattern](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) at startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally Removed SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42572/accidentally-removed-sd-card)

Comment: It worked after inserting the sd into PC, as soon as it is viewable by explorer, it boots with no problem, just needed to wait

Comment: maybe the PC corrected the filesystem somehow